# How to calculate a bank's deposit growth from one call report to the next, as a percentage?

Tags: google-bigquery

I downloaded the entire FDIC bank call reports dataset, and uploaded it to BigQuery.

The table I currently have looks like this:
[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is adding a column showing the deposit growth rate since the last quarter for each bank:
Note:The first reporting date for each bank (e.g. 19921231) will not have a "Quarterly Deposit Growth". Hence the two empty cells for the two banks.
[image]

**I would like to know if a bank is increasing or decreasing its deposits each quarter/call report (viewed as a percentage).**

e.g. "On their last call report (19921231)First National Bank had deposits of 456789 (in 1000's). In their next call report (19930331)First National bank had deposits of 567890 (in 1000's). What is the percentage increase (or decrease) in deposits"?

This "_%_Change_in_Deposits" column would be displayed as a new column.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
select 
SFRNLL.repdte, SFRNLL.cert, SFRNLL.name, SFRNLL.city, SFRNLL.county, SFRNLL.stalp, SFRNLL.specgrp AS `Loan_Specialization`, SFRNLL.lnreres as `_1_to_4_Residential_Loans`, AL.dep as `Deposits`, AL.lnlsnet as `loans_and_leases`, 
IEEE_DIVIDE(SFRNLL.lnreres, AL.lnlsnet) as SFR2TotalLoanRatio

FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_1_4_Family_Residential_Net_Loans_and_Leases  as SFRNLL

JOIN usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL
ON SFRNLL.cert = AL.cert 
where SFRNLL.specgrp = 4 and IEEE_DIVIDE(SFRNLL.lnreres, AL.lnlsnet) <= 0.10

UNION ALL


select 
SFRNLL.repdte, SFRNLL.cert, SFRNLL.name, SFRNLL.city, SFRNLL.county, SFRNLL.stalp, SFRNLL.specgrp AS `Loan_Specialization`, SFRNLL.lnreres as `_1_to_4_Residential_Loans`, AL.dep as `Deposits`, AL.lnlsnet as `loans_and_leases`, 
IEEE_DIVIDE(SFRNLL.lnreres, AL.lnlsnet) as SFR2TotalLoanRatio

FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_1_4_Family_Residential_Net_Loans_and_Leases  as SFRNLL

JOIN usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL
ON SFRNLL.cert = AL.cert 
where SFRNLL.specgrp = 4 and IEEE_DIVIDE(SFRNLL.lnreres, AL.lnlsnet) <= 0.10
```

The table looks like this:

[image: Results of query in BigQuery. This is the first quarter/call report]

[image: Results of following quarter(call report)]

Additional notes:

1. I would also like to view the last column (SFR2TotalLoansRatio) as a percentage.
2. This code runs correctly, however, previously I  was getting a "division by zero" error when attempting to run 50,000 rows (1992 to the present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing each of your question individually.

**First)** Retrieving `SFR2TotalLoanRatio` as percentage, I assume you want to see `9.988%` instead of `0.0988` in your results. Currently, in BigQuery you can achieve this by casting the field into a `STRING` then, concatenating the `%` sign. Below there is an example with sample data:

```
WITH data as (
SELECT 0.0123 as percentage UNION ALL
SELECT 0.0999 as percentage UNION ALL
SELECT 0.3456 as percentage
)
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(percentage*100 as String),"%") as formatted_percentage  FROM data
```

And the output,

```
Row formatted_percentage
1   1.23%
2   9.99%
3   34.56%
```

**Second)** Regarding your question about the `division by zero error`. I am assuming `IEEE_DIVIDE(arg1,arg2)` is a function to perform the division, in which `arg1` is the divisor and `arg2` is the dividend. Therefore, I would adivse your to explore your data in order to figured out which records have divisor equals to zero. After gathering these results, you can determine what to do with them. In case you decide to discard them you can simply add within your `WHERE` statement in each of your **JOIN**s: `AL.lnlsnet = 0`. On the other hand, you can also modify the records where `lnlsnet = 0` using a [CASE WHEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions) or [IF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if) statements.

UPDATE:

In order to add this piece of code your query, you u have to wrap your code within a temporary table. Then, I will make two adjustments, first a temporary function in order to calculate the percentage and format it with the ***%*** sign. Second, retrieving the previous number of deposits to calculate the desired percentage. *I am also assuming that `cert` is the individual id for each of the bank's clients.* The modifications will be as follows:

```
#the following function MUST be the first thing within your query
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION percent(dep INT64, prev_dep INT64) AS (
  Concat(Cast((dep-prev_dep)/prev_dep*100 AS STRING), "%")
);

#followed by the query you have created so far as a temporary table, notice the the comma I added after the last parentheses
WITH data AS(
#your query
),
#within this second part you need to select all the columns from data, and LAG function will be used to retrieve the previous number of deposits  for each client
data_2 as (
SELECT repdte, cert, name, city, county, stalp, Loan_Specialization, _1_to_4_Residential_Loans,Deposits, loans_and_leases, SFR2TotalLoanRatio, 
CASE WHEN cert = lag(cert) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d) THEN  lag(Deposits) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) ELSE NULL END AS prev_dep FROM data
)
SELECT repdte, cert, name, city, county, stalp, Loan_Specialization, _1_to_4_Residential_Loans,Deposits, loans_and_leases, SFR2TotalLoanRatio, percent(Deposits,prev_dep) as dept_growth_rate FROM data_2
```

Note that the built-in function [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) is used together with [CASE WHEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr) in order to retrieve the previous amount of deposits per client.

Comment: I edited question (added before and after tables) for clarification.  Am still curious as to how  I would  query the quarterly bank deposit growth rate.

Comment: @user2755660, I have added the piece you requested within the answer. Please, you you found the answer useful consider accepting and upvoting the answer.